# Meta-Analysis: Effect size calculation - p-value

Tags: meta-analysis

Is it possible to calculate an effect size if only a p-value and sample sizes of two independet groups are given?

Kind regards
Joanne

Comment: What kind of 'effect size' measure would you like to compute? There are many types. Often, people use 'effect size' synonymously with 'standardized mean difference' (i.e., Cohen's d), but the term itself is ambiguous.

Comment: I would like to compute Hedges g.

Comment: Check the following web site:
https://www.campbellcollaboration.org/escalc/html/EffectSizeCalculator-SMD7.php
By Practical Meta-Analysis Effect Size Calculator
David B. Wilson, Ph.D., George Mason University

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the p-value you have is based on an independent samples t-test, then you can do the following:

1. If the p-value is for a two-sided test, divide the p-value by 2, so it becomes a one-sided p-value. For example, if the two-sided p-value is .046, then the one-sided $p = .023$.
2. Convert the one-sided p-value to the corresponding t-statistic. The degrees of freedom for the t-distribution are $n_1 + n_2 - 2$, where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the group sizes. For example, if the (one-sided) p-value is .023 and $n_1 = 23$ and $n_2 = 27$, then $t = 2.048508$. One can use tables for this lookup or use software like R (e.g., `qt(.023, df = 23+27-2, lower.tail = FALSE)` in R).
3. Convert the t-statistic to Cohen's d with: $$d = t \times \sqrt{1/n_1 + 1/n_2}.$$ So, continuing the example, this would be: $$d = 2.048508 \times \sqrt{1/23 + 1/27} = 0.5812686.$$
4. Convert Cohen's d to Hedges' g by applying the bias-correction: $$g = \left(1 - \frac{3}{4(n_1 + n_2 - 2) - 1}\right) \times d.$$ So, in the example: $$g = \left(1 - \frac{3}{4(23 + 27 - 2) - 1}\right) = 0.5721388,$$ which we then can round to 0.57.

**Notes:**

1. Again, this conversion of a p-value to Cohen's d / Hedges' g only makes sense when the p-value comes from an independent samples t-test.
2. Moreover, the independent samples t-test must have been a t-test assuming equal variances in the two groups (the 'homoscedasticity assumption'). If the t-test was a [Welsh's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t-test), then this conversion is not appropriate.
3. If the p-value was two-sided to begin with, you do not know whether the sign of the d or g value should be positive or negative. So, the two-sided p-value of .046 above corresponds to $g = 0.57$ or $g = -0.57$. You will need further information (from the article/source from which the p-value has come) to determine the correct sign.
4. The conversion is in principle exact, but since reported p-values are often rounded, this will introduce some error into the computations. That's usually not a major concern though.
5. However, if the p-value is truncated (e.g., all you know is that $p \le .05$ or some other cutoff), then this is a problem. Some people might assume $p = .05$ then (which will be overly conservative), others might assume that the p-value is then halfway between 0 and the cutoff, so $p = .025$ (which will be conservative or liberal depending on what the exact p-value actually was), and some people might then just decide not to convert the p-value to d or g due to insufficient information.